# Problem Sending my FlowDocument to the Printer

Tags: wpf

I have a FlowDocumentScrollViewer control in my project, in this I have a FlowDocument in this I have five BlockUIContainers, each of these BlockUIContainers houses a table of values created by ListView controls, prior to each block I have the respective headers. All my content is displayed as expected, however when sending it to print a problems occur, that is, a single page of each listView is printed.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Clone the source document
        var str = XamlWriter.Save(flowDocument);
        var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(str);
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        var CloneDoc = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as FlowDocument;

        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

        if (pd.ShowDialog().Value)
        {
            CloneDoc.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
            CloneDoc.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;
            CloneDoc.PagePadding = new Thickness(40, 50, 40, 40);
            CloneDoc.ColumnGap = 0;
            CloneDoc.ColumnWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;

            IDocumentPaginatorSource idocument = CloneDoc;
            pd.PrintDocument(idocument.DocumentPaginator, "flow doc");
        }
    }
```